# cancel reply link results in 404 error

Tags: comments, 404-error, links

Our blog is in a subdirectory of the WebPage `http://example.com/blog`. 
Here is an example of a cancel reply link:

`<a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/postcategory/postname.html#respond"> style="display:none;">cancel reply</a></small>`

As you can see, cancel reply links to `domain.com/postcategory/postname.html#respond`, which results in a 404 error.

How can I find a workaround without disabling comments?

I've already tried filtering in the `functions.php`, but that disabled the comment function somehow completely:

`add_filter( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', '__return_false' );`

Kind regards for your immediate help.

Comment: I don't think that this is the cause of your problem, but I think you shouldn't be using `__return_false` as filter function, as filters are expected to return strings. I think a better choice would be to use [`__return_empty_string`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string) as filter function.

Comment: Hi, why don't you simply use CSS if you just want to disable reply link?

Comment: @Jack it is actually not displayed by css but, the wrong url is still parsed by google, giving me a hell lot of 404 sites in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this filter to fully modify the link and it's text:

`apply_filters( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', $formatted_link, $link, $text );`

You can modify the proper value depending on your needs. You might also be able to use a `preg_replace()` to modify the link and add your `/blog/` value to it.

To remove the link entirely, use:

`add_filter( 'cancel_comment_reply_link', '', '', '' );`

Comment: cool, thanks...could you pls show me how?

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer. The code goes in your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: Hey jack.. I will try, thanks... could you be so kind as to elaborate how to use the preg_replace() in the functions.php to simply add the
domain.com/blog      to the front of the correct rest of our url, which is there?  Kind regards... (i am a noob in programming, pls excuse)

Comment: This way I would receive a correct link to a correct site instead of disabling the cancel link to a wrong site. - deleting the cancel link would result in a bad user experience, if the user clicks on one comment but decides to answer to an other, as both comment fields would still be open. Kind regards...